# Reorganize Dataframe values according to the same values across rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Dataframe, I would want to reorganize the dataframe sp that it takes only matching values in rows and other fill it with Nan:-

Columns A, B, C, D :-

Input Dataframe

```
|A    |B    |C    |D|
|1    |2    |3    |4|
|5    |6    |1    |8|
|9    |1    |2    |6|
```

Expecting Output as =

```
|A        |B         |C         |D|
|1        |1         |1        |Nan|
|5       |Nan       |Nan       |Nan|
|9       |Nan       |Nan       |Nan|
|Nan     |2          |2        |Nan|
|Nan     |6         |Nan        |6|
|Nan    |Nan         |3        |Nan|
|Nan    |Nan        |Nan       |4|
|Nan    |Nan        |Nan       |8|
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
dfc = df.stack().reset_index()
df_out = dfc.set_index([dfc[0], 'level_1'])[0].unstack()
df_out.sort_values(['A','B','C'])
```

Output:

```
level_1    A    B    C    D
0                          
1        1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
5        5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
9        9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2        NaN  2.0  2.0  NaN
6        NaN  6.0  NaN  6.0
3        NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN
4        NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
8        NaN  NaN  NaN  8.0
```

The tricks are to stack the dataframe columns, then add a new multiindex with the "values", df[0], and original column headers, 'level_1', then unstack the column headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott !
Indeed, it helped me and solved my problem.